# How to trigger action in different platforms / applications

Tags: android, ios, reactjs, publish-subscribe, multiplatform

I am trying to build a process to notify all my applications about a user who changed his information.

At the moment I have a web application (React), an iOS application (Swift) and an Android application (Java).
All of the three applications have a section called My profile where the user can see his basic information.

Here the user is able to change his nickname (this nickname is a value that we show to the user almost every page in the web application and in the native apps we get the nickname when the user opens the application).

When the user changes his nickname, I want to notify the native apps and the web application so they can retrieve the new nickname.

**Problem:**

WEB - There is no universal service to get the nickname of the user, at first we add that nickname to a service that is already in multiple pages but not in all of them, after a quick check to our web app we found at least 9 services where the nickname should be added to cover all the scenarios.

APP - When user opens the app it calls the/basicInfo service to get the user data (where the nickname is included) but when user has the app in background and returns to it the service is not being called due to performance issue (the /basicInfo service returns multiple user data and has to do multiple queries to the DB).

I could think of a couple of solutions:

1. To create a new service that only does one query to the DB in order to retrieve the nickname. This could be a lightweight service that can be called on every section of our web and apps without having to worry about performance.
2. I am not sure if we can use pubSub to notify all the applications when the user changes his nickname so they can call the current /basicInfo service. With this approach we don't have to create a new service we use the already existing and the performance is not an issue since it will be called only when necessary. But I have never used pubSub not even sure if it can work like described previously.
3. To create an new lightweight service to retrieve only the nickname of the user and also use pubSub to call this service only when necessary (when we detect the change event) If possible this could be the best option.

What would you recommend and why?

Thanks in advance.